# JAVA create cycle with multiple ResultSet

Tags: java

```
int i=0, j=0;
    query = "SELECT * FROM game WHERE GameRound = '"+status.getRound()+"'"; 
    st = conn.createStatement();
    rs = st.executeQuery(query);
    while(rs.next()){
        query = "SELECT Id FROM team WHERE Name ='"+rs.getString("Team1")+"'";
        result += "</br>"+query;
        st3 = conn.createStatement();
        rs3 = st3.executeQuery(query);
        if(rs3.next()){
            game.setTeamA(groupTeamForGame(rs3.getInt("Id")));// id
            i++;
        }
          ...........
          j++;
    }
```

I am trying to get a list of teams from my DB. `While` cycle works fine, and returns 8 queries as it expects, but i have problem with `rs3` - it runs only once and i get only first value in `game.setTeamA(groupTeamForGame(rs3.getInt("Id")));`
/At the end `i = 1 , j = 8` /

Comment: Did you try to replace `if(rs3.next())` with `while(rs3.next())`?

Comment: `rs3` have always 1 row

Comment: What is the problem then?

Comment: the if statement must run with each `while` cycle which is 8 times, but it run only once

Comment: Why are you doing this? You can execute this in one loop by using an SQL join. Something like `SELECT t.id FROM team t, game g WHERE g.GameRound = status.getRound() AND t.name=g.Team1`.

Answer (score 0):

> but i have problem with rs3 - it runs only once and i get only first value

You write `if(rs3.next())` so that will run once only.

Comment: Cycle `while(rs.next()){` runs 8 times, for each cycle i have different query which means different  `rs3` value, so the problem is with statement or resultset i think

Comment: As `i` is incremented once only so that makes sure that condition `if(rs3.next())` is `true` once only. So check if data exists for all the 8 teams??

Comment: Problem solved, there was a blank space in database values, thanks!